How to solve rsync permission error regression in Alpine 3.20.2
I have a permission problem with rsync in a Alpine 3.20.2 docker image, which does not occur in a Alpine 3.19 image.
If I run the following code
docker run -it --rm alpine:3.19
apk add rsync
rsync -a /etc/ /mnt/

rsync copies /etc content tom /mnt
If I do the same with an Alpine 3.20.2 image
docker run -it --rm alpine:3.20.2
apk add rsync
rsync -a /etc/ /mnt/
rsync: [generator] failed to set permissions on "/mnt/apk": Operation not permitted (1)

I get a lot of permission errors.
I already tried the proposed solution from Rsync in chrooted ssh in alpine docker image result in failed to set permissions, but without luck. In addition, the file /etc/rsyncd.conf is the same in both images.
I suspect that the problem has something todo with Linux capabilities, but that is just a guess.
